# Как работают прототипы? Почему через прототип не меняется свойство obj?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Почему через прототип не меняется свойство obj?

```
var obj = {
    val:"num"
}

var obj2 = {
    value:2
}

obj2.__proto__ = obj;

console.log( obj2.val );//Берем значение из прототипа = num

obj2.val = 3; //Меняем значение свойства val обьекта obj на 3

console.log( obj.val ); // => num. Ожидаю 3
console.log( obj2.val );// =>3


delete obj2.val;

console.log( obj2.val ); // => num. ожидаю undefined

console.log( obj.val ); // => num. ожидаю undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае используются три операции:

1. получение свойства объекта
2. задание свойства объекта
3. удаление свойства объекта

---

### Получение свойства

1. Если у объекта присутствует запрашиваемое свойство, его значение будет возвращено.
2. Если у объекта нет запрашиваемого свойства, запрос будет переадресован объекту прототипа. Так будет продолжаться до тех пор пока прототип не станет равен *null*.

---

### Задание свойства

1. Если у объекта присутствует свойство, которому нужно задать значение, то значение этого свойства будет обновлено
2. Если у объекта отсутствует свойство, которому нужно задать значение, то свойство будет **добавлено в объект** с указанным значением.

---

### Удаление свойства

1. Если у объекта присутствует свойство, которое нужно удалить, то свойство будет удалено, и будет возвращено `true`
2. Если у объекта отсутствует свойство, будет возвращено `false`

---

В связи с этим код из вопроса можно прокомментировать так:

```
var obj = {
    val:"num"
}

var obj2 = {
    value:2
}

obj2.__proto__ = obj;

console.log( obj2.val );// в obj2 Нет свойства `val`, смотрим в прототип (obj) -> берем значение из прототипа

obj2.val = 3; // в obj2 Нет свойства `val`, создаем свойство `val` и присваиваем ему значение `3`

console.log( obj.val ); // => у объекта присутствует запрашиваемое свойство его значение возвращается -> num
console.log( obj2.val );// => у объекта присутствует запрашиваемое свойство его значение возвращается ->3


delete obj2.val; // удаляем из `obj2` свойство `val`

console.log( obj2.val ); // => в obj2 Нет свойства `val`, смотрим в прототип (obj) -> берем значение из прототипа

console.log( obj.val ); // => num. Объект `obj` не менялся ни в одной строчке, следовательно значение то же, что и в начале.
```

Comment: Побывал @Grundy - пропускаем, отличный ответ уже есть, ищем неотвеченные вопросы далее :)